# INSERT ... SELECT PHP

Tags: php, sql, insert, syntax-error

I need a new pair of eyes to help me spot what's wrong with my code.

```
 <?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$sql = "INSERT INTO pets (owner_service, Gender, Age, Size, Location, idealLocation, Service, memberID) 
        SELECT ('{$_POST['owner_service']}', '{$_POST['gender']}', '{$_POST['age']}', '{$_POST['size']}', '$locationCommaString', '{$_POST['ideal_location']}', '{$_POST['service']}', memberID FROM members WHERE username = '{$_POST['username']}')";


        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "successful";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

?>
```

The error says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM members WHERE username = '')' at line 2

MySQL version is 5.5.41

Comment: Why are you combining INSERT and SELECT statements together?

Comment: Please add the complete message. Learn about prepared statements. It is much more readable and safty

Comment: ( parenthesis , after Select, remove panthesis from both end

Comment: @Sagar OP try to copy data from one table to another.

Comment: Isn't the syntax `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ....) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM other_table WHERE condition = thing` ? (*Without the `()` by the `SELECT` statement*). It seems you're only trying to select the `memberID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it must be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pets (owner_service, Gender, Age, Size, Location, idealLocation, Service, memberID) 
        SELECT '{$_POST['owner_service']}', '{$_POST['gender']}', '{$_POST['age']}', '{$_POST['size']}', '$locationCommaString', '{$_POST['ideal_location']}', '{$_POST['service']}', memberID FROM members WHERE username = '{$_POST['username']}'";
```

You have to remove parenthesis after `SELECT` and at the end of the statement.
Also you have to learn about prepared statement.

Comment: of course! Such a little mistake! Thanks for pointing it out.